# How can I use %glr-parser and support %define api.pure full in Bison?

Tags: bison

I’m using C language in Bison and I need %glr-parser and api.pure full, but as far as I know, the C language mode in Bison seems to not support the use of %glr-parser and api.pure full at the same time. Is there any solution?